# How to extract differences between dictionaries?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2, nsdictionary

I can compare whether 2 dictionaries match or not like this:

```
func ==(lhs: [String: AnyObject], rhs: [String: AnyObject] ) -> Bool {
    return NSDictionary(dictionary: lhs).isEqualToDictionary(rhs)
}
```

Is there a concise way to extract the differences between 2 dictionaries, as in the opposite of the intersection?

Comment: What difference(s), specifically? Given two dictionaries, each might have keys that aren't in the other. For keys that exist in both, they might have different values. That gives you two possible sets of keys plus one possible set of different values.

Comment: Yes, if a key doesn't exist in the other, then it would be considered a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can define an operator to check whether 2 dictionaries contains the same keys and for each key the same value.

### Value must be Equatable

First of all we need to use generics to require that the `Value` of the dictionaries conforms to `Equatable` otherwise we won't be able to compare the values.

### The code

Here's the code

```
func ==<Value:Equatable>(left: [String: Value], right: [String: Value]) -> Bool {
    guard left.keys.count == right.keys.count else { return  false }
    let differenceFound = zip(left.keys.sort(), right.keys.sort()).contains { elm -> Bool in
        let leftKey = elm.0
        let rightKey = elm.1
        return leftKey != rightKey || left[leftKey] != right[rightKey]
    }
    return !differenceFound
}
```

The first line verify that the dictionaries have the same number of entries, otherwise `false` is returned.

The next block of code sort the keys of both dictionaries and compare each pair looking for a pair where the keys or the values are different.

If such difference is not found then the dictionaries have the same keys and values, so they are equals.

### Examples

```
["a":1, "b": 2] == ["a":1, "b": 2] // true
```

Of course since values inside a dictionaries don't have an order the following is still true

```
["a":1, "b": 2] == ["b":2, "a": 1] // true
```

In the next example we compare 2 dictionaries with a different number of values

```
["a":1, "b": 2] == ["a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3] // false
```

### The != operator

Since we defined the `==` operator, Swift gifts us the `!=` operator (which simply returns the opposite of `==`), so we can also write

```
["a":1, "b": 2] != ["d":4] // true
```

### Shorter version

The same operator can also be written in this shorter way

```
func ==<Value:Equatable>(left: [String: Value], right: [String: Value]) -> Bool {
    return
        left.keys.count == right.keys.count &&
        !zip(left.keys.sort(), right.keys.sort()).contains { $0 != $1 || left[$0] != right[$1] }
}
```

### Update

Now given 2 dictionaries `a` and `b`, you want to perform `a.minus(b)` and get as result a new dictionaries containing all the `(key, value)` pairs available in `a` and not available in `b`.

Here's the code

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable, Value: Equatable {
    func minus(dict: [Key:Value]) -> [Key:Value] {
        let entriesInSelfAndNotInDict = filter { dict[$0.0] != self[$0.0] }
        return entriesInSelfAndNotInDict.reduce([Key:Value]()) { (res, entry) -> [Key:Value] in
            var res = res
            res[entry.0] = entry.1
            return res
        }
    }
}
```

Examples

```
["a":1].minus(["a":2]) // ["a": 1]
["a":1].minus(["a":1]) // [:]
["a":1].minus(["a":1, "b":2]) // [:]
["a":1, "b": 2].minus(["a":1]) // ["b": 2]
```

Comment: I was trying to find the differences, so maybe an extension like this? `extension Dictionary where Key: NSObject, Value:AnyObject { func difference(other: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> [NSObject: AnyObject] {...} }`. So it would be the opposite of the interaction or a filter for the differences.

Comment: @TruMan1: One question. Given these 2 dictionaries `let dict0 = ["a":1]` and `let dict1 =  ["b":2]`. What should the difference method return?

Comment: Good question: `["a": 1, "b": 2]`

Comment: Or another example: `["a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3].difference(["b": 2, "c": 4]) => ["a": 1, "c": 3]`

Comment: @TruMan1: Ok got it

Comment: "union minus the intersection", oh ya that's a concise way of thinking about it!

Comment: @TruMan1 in your last example, what is the logic behind choosing `"c":3` instead of `"c":4`? The dictionaries differ there.

Comment: @TruMan1: I added a new section at the end of my answer, please check it out.

Comment: @TomHarrington: I think he wants all the `(key,value)` pairs in the first dictionary and not in the second one.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to compare JSON objects saturated into models and testing if changes have been made to it before exiting a screen.

Answer (score 2):

[Swift supports operations like symmetricDifference(*:) and subtracting(*:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html), but for sets, not dictionaries. Depending on your need, you could diff the keys and then reconstruct the resulting dictionary with map.